# Load data without hard refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Case: An user purchases an airplane ticket from American Airline on my website. It takes an hour for the order to get processed, after which I need to show a navigation tab.

Question: I don't want the user to refresh the page to load the data. Is there something that can trigger an API call an hour later after the user's ticket purchase?

I'm using AngularJS, Express, NodeJS.

Update:

1. I thought about using setTimeout(fn, delay) to initiate a timer and then use clearInterval(id) to close it after request success. However, the browser executes on a single thread asynchronously so the timer delay is not guaranteed. In addition:

   - If the user put the computer to sleep, the setTimeout would freeze.
   - If the user switched tab, the setTimeout function becomes inaccurate.
   - The setTimeout behavior could be different in different browsers.
2. I also consider about node-cron, but I still need to make a node call automatically because the navigation controller is loaded on app start. This means the user still has to do a hard refresh to see the navigation tab.
3. Is there a way to use browser cache to do it?

Comment: You could just use the JavaScript function setTimeout.  But there a good chance that your user is going to close the browser before an hour passes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript, you can dynamically load and change data.

for example below code will get triggered every minute and inside, you can perform asynchronous tasks such as calling http requests, and dynamically update value.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
//perform async task and get new value
document.getElementById('DOM').value = "NEW VALUE";
}, 60000);
```